# Rails fetch url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I fetch a URL & its data in rails?

I've tried using open-uri:

```
@r = open("http://google.com/").read
```

This works for me in `ruby` but not in rails.

If you can suggest a better way to fetch a url (if there is one) let me know!

Comment: are you getting an error when you do that in rails?

Comment: It says `No such file or directory` odd considering its a URL

Comment: In my opinion `open-uri` is really poorly written. It requires a formal "URL" in the strict sense so it will accept "http://google.com" but not "google.com" or "www.google.com". It's *technically* correct but it's not made for practical use at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `require 'open-uri'` in order to use `open` on urls in Rails.